# Why setValue at not working on Jtable?

Tags: java, jtable

I am doing project on java.
In one of the class, I am working on jtable.
Now what i am doing is,

- In the table data will be loaded from the database.

Now i want to change some value at some exact row and column.

so for that i am using jtable's setValue function.
which is like this....

```
grayCardTbl.setValueAt(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(pdiff)),1,4);
```

I have checked the "pdiff" variable, it is perfect.

i had total 5 columns and 10 rows. So now problem with rowindex and column index.

and after this i have also refresh the table. but still it is not reflecting on table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JTable.setValueAt(...)` method calls `TableModel.setValueAt(...)`.

My guess is that you've not implemented it in the model and the data doesn't get updated.

**Edit**: if your model calls `JTable.setValueAt(...)`, it's going to loop into a stackoverflow. What you need to do is **actually** update the underlying data.

For instance if your model's `getValueAt(...)` does `return data[row][column]`, then `setValueAt(...)` needs to do `data[row][column] = value;`

Comment: I had written something like this...in setValueAt()..........

public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
if(columnIndex == 4){
         this.table.setValueAt(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(aValue)), rowIndex, columnIndex);   
            table.tableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this));
        }
}